# Access to Canvas in one class from another

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I created a class XYZ which extends SurfaceView. Inside onDraw method I create a bitmap array with images and then I used method drawBitmap to place the image on my canvas. This looks more or less like this:

```
public class Board extends SurfaceView{


   public BitmapFactory myBitmapFactory = new BitmapFactory();
   public  Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap();
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image), size, size, false);

Paint paint = new Paint();
canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, x, y, paint);
```

And I have a second class, it's MyActivity, where after clicking a button I want to change the image on my canvas:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public Context context = this;
     public Board myGameBoard;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_game);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
}

public void changeImage(View view){
   //here I want to change the image
   }
}
```

(I posted only the most important lines of code, which i think are responsible for adding an image).

But i don't know how to get to the canvas which I was using inside the onDraw method, because it's a local variable. How sholud I do that to be able to change the image?

Answer (score 1):

Add a new setter to your `Board` class, e.g. `setBitmap(Bitmap)`. Save the bitmap reference there and invalidate the view so that `onDraw()` is called again. In `onDraw` read the bitmap that was set. Done!